# Can't get Dynamic Data Display working with WPF Browser Application

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0, dynamic-data-display

Can I get [Dynamic Data Display](https://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/) library working with WPF Browser App? I'm getting "Target Invocation Exception" when attempting to launch the app, regular desktop WPF app runs just fine.

Update 1: "That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers." is the error, got it by adding D3's chart plotter dynamically. Looking into it now.

Comment: i just check my browser application with the library .. 

its working

you should try downloading the library from https://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/ 

and check 1 more time....

Comment: that's exactly what i did

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by switching to "This is a full trust application" option in the Security tab of my project's properties. May not be appropriate for everyone, check for the potential implications of it. Did the trick for me though.

Comment: as usual default settings are the most protective so had to tweak it abit!